# Offloading TLS client-cert checking to OpenSSL (or similar) if server does not support it

Tags: tls, authentication, certificates, openssl, client-side

## TL;DR

I want to have "some thing" to handle client-certs on behalf a server that is unable to do it, for secure user authentication in addition to regular TLS encryption.

## Context

In this question [How can I double check security against a TLS on a public IP?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/230893/233270) the answers set clear that regular TLS does not typically do client authentication, although it seems it would be possible if the server requests it.

Let's suppose I have a server that is able to communicate via "plain text" or "on a TLS channel" (I can re-start the server with or without TLS), but if TLS is enabled, the server does not support checking client-certificates for auth.

The original question was for a docker registry, but I generalize the question to any server supporting TLS but not client-side certs.

## What I'm thinking

I am thinking of offloading the "TLS part" to a security-specific software (much similar to what SSH port-forwarding tunnels are) and decouple the server and the TLS handling.

Probably there would be 2 processes involved:

- The server listens in a firewalled localhost port or a linux socket in "plain text", but as it is firewalled it can never be reached from the outside.
- Some kind of "security middleware" (Probably OpenSSL, but I'm not sure) -I think it'd be called a TLS terminator, but I'm neither really sure, too- to do this:

  - Handle the public-IP listening
  - Handle the server-side certs to secure the channel via TLS
  - Handle the client-side certs to check authenticity (probably against a set of public keys I'll have previously uploaded in the server)
  - If and only if the client belongs to a white-list of users, then forward the decrypted channel to the regualar plain-text server.

## Questions

1. Would be this TLS offloading a normal setup?
2. If so, is OpenSSL a good handler for this offloading?
3. If yes, what documentation could be a good starting point for this kind of setup, where I can read on and learn?

Thnx.

Comment: You won't receive a client certificate unless you ask for it. Your server can undoubtedly be configured to ask for it.

Comment: Cross-referenced here https://forums.docker.com/t/have-docker-regsitry-tls-to-check-client-certificates-for-user-auth/93422/3?u=xavimontero

Answer (score 6):

> 1. Would be this TLS offloading a normal setup?

Offloading TLS to *something else* if your server doesn't support what you want is a normal setup.

> 2. If so, is OpenSSL a good handler for this offloading?

I would not expect to build a solution for this directly with openssl.  Load balancers do this sort of thing all the time.  You can also do it with stunnel; [here is an example setup](http://blog.siphos.be/2012/12/using-stunnel-for-mutual-authentication/), boiling down to these key config lines:

```
verify = 2 # This enables the mutual authentication
CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/root-genfic.crt
```

Where client certs are signed by root-genfic.crt.

> 3. If yes, what documentation could be a good starting point for this kind of setup, where I can read on and learn?

stunnel documentation and related resources are available at the [stunnel web site](https://www.stunnel.org/docs.html).